# Javascript Loop isn't stopping.. My result disappears after a sliver of a second

Tags: javascript, function, loops, debugging

My javascript function asks to define variables that move the user through quiz questions, adding or subtracting numbers and reaching a total which is called later in an HTML form. All is working, but instead of the loop ending on the client-side result, it flashes on-screen and disappears, as if the script is waiting for the user to start the questions over again. Am I correct in feeling that the problem is in the javascript loop somewhere? Thanks:

```
var max_points = 28;
var total_points = 0;
var percentage_addiction = 0;

var reloadVar = "yes";

function makeChanges(currentQuestion, nextQuestion, points){
//display only needed question
document.getElementById(currentQuestion).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display="block";

//add total points
total_points = total_points + points;

//show image that corresponds to points
for( var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    if( ( total_points > i*2 ) && ( total_points <= (i+1)*2 ) )
    {
        //hide image that was shown previously
        document.getElementById('img' + i).style.display="none";

        //display image that corresponds points
        document.getElementById("img"+(i+1)).style.display="block";
    }
}

percentage_addiction = Math.floor( (total_points/max_points)*100 );

if( nextQuestion == "result" )
{
    document.getElementById("code").style.display="block";
    //document.form1.percentage.value=escape(document.percentage); 
    location.replace('http://URL?percentage='+percentage_addiction+'&end=yes&oneSubmit=yes');
}

//update percentage in page
document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = percentage_addiction;
document.getElementById('percentage2').innerHTML = percentage_addiction;
}


function submitForm(){
document.form1.submit();
}
```

Comment: did u check the loop with FireFox FireBug??if not , please check it.

Comment: I have checked the script in Firebug but admit I am useless when trying to debug.. don't know what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is running automatically after the results are displayed:

```
location.replace( 'http://URL?percentage=' + percentage_addiction + '&end=yes&oneSubmit=yes' );
```

This is causing the result to disappear after a sliver of a second. Remove it or bind it to a button or a link in the document.